# Jboss export excel for large data

Tags: excel, jboss, export-to-excel

I am using Jboss 7.1 developer edition.

Currently i am using Apache poi for the excel export.

But i unable to export the large data from this jar, i want some other solution for the excel export.

While i try to use Apache poi , its endup with out of memory exception.

Approximately i need to export 50 X 8 cells in one sheet , totally 40 sheets in a single export

I saw some suggestion of , jboss seam excel export. Will it be helpful for me.

Please suggest any solution for this.

Thanks,

Ram.K

Answer (score 0):

With [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net) you can choose if process data in memory or if use temporary files ([setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(boolean)](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/WorkbookSettings.html#setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(boolean))).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on EasyXLS Excel library:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/getting-started/easyxls-java-excel-library.html

Here you can find some directions on how to use EasyXLS for better performance:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/tips-and-tricks/export-large-excel-file.html